# TypeError: _services_wordpressApi__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.getPosts is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to use rest api in wp to list all posts. I keep getting the above error. I've tried everything I can think of.

I've tried combining it all into a single page, I have tried changing the getPosts arrow function to an actual function, I've spent hours searching for a solution online...

Any suggestions how to fix this?

**wordpressApi.js**

```
const baseurl = 'http://qdgwpsites.local/';
const restUrl = 'wp-json/wp/v2/';
const postsEndpoint = 'posts';
const pagesEndpoint = 'pages';
const categoriesEndpoint = 'categories';

const getPosts = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const endpoint = baseurl + restUrl + postsEndpoint;
    
    console.log("API URL " + endpoint);

    fetch(endpoint)
    .then(response => response.json()
    .then(json => ({
        totalPages: response.headers.get("x-wp-totalpages"),
        totalPosts: response.headers.get("x-wp-total"),
        allHeaders: response.headers,
        json
      })))
    .then(result => {
        resolve(result);
    }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
  });
```

**PostTitles.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import apiData from '../../services/wordpressApi';



export default function PostTitles() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    
    const getPostsData = async () => {
        try {
          await apiData.getPosts()
            .then((data) => {    
              setPosts(data.json);
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };

    useEffect(() => {
        getPostsData();
        
   }, [])
  return (
    
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post) =>
          <li key={post.id}>
          {post.title.rendered}
        </li>
      )}
    </ul>
 );
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.scss";
import PostTitles from "./components/PostTitles/PostTitles";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">React JS WordPress api example</header>
      <PostTitles />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export `getPosts` function like below. Then only you can import it in another component.

```
export const getPosts = () => ...
```